# Django CBV inheritance: Overriding attributes

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-class-based-views

I'm creating custom class based views for a Django project and faced a design decision concerning attributes.

#### Getter functions

I looked at Django's generic views, and saw that there are quite a lot of classes that provide both class variables as well as custom getter functions. [e.g](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L14).

```
class FormMixin(object):
    initial = {}
    def get_initial(self):
        return self.initial
```

This design decision makes sense, because that way, you can call `super()` in an overriding method of an extending class.

#### Properties

In my project, there are certain values that I could sometimes override using a simple value, but that sometimes have to be generated dnyamically. At first I created methods similar to the above, but then thought that maybe properties are a nicer way to do this.

```
class MyBaseView(OtherView):
    counter = None

class MyExtendingView(MyBaseView):
    counter = 5

class MyOtherExtendingView(MyBaseView):
    @property
    def counter(self):
        return self.other_function()
```

#### instance.__dict__

I plan on using those values inside a template. I pass instances of the extending views to a template and display the attributes in the following way:

```
context['class_instances'] = [MyExtendingView(), MyOtherExtendingView()]

{% for instance in class_instances %}
    {{ instance.counter|default:'' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now as this is a template, and it doesn't really matter whether the instance attribute is a value or a function, I could also write my classes like this:

```
class MyExtendingView(MyBaseView):
    counter = 5

class MyOtherExtendingView(MyBaseView):
    def counter(self):
        return self.other_function()
```

The `def counter` will replace the old value-based attribute in `instance.__dict__`.

#### Question

To get to the question, which of the listed approaches is the best choice?

- The getter approach is nice, as it allows `super()`-calling the parent's getter function, but in most of my cases that will probably never be needed.
- The property approach is much simpler and causes less code to be written. I can't `super()`-call a parent's property function though. I won't be needing this behavior in most cases, but there could be cases where I need `super()` functionality, so there would be a mix of simple attributes that can be overridden using properties and custom getter functions.
- The last approach is even less code than the property approach, but I doubt it's good style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The property approach is much simpler and causes less code to be written. I can't super()-call a parent's property function though.

You actually can access parent properties via `super()`:

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def prop(self):
        return 'A.prop'

class B(A):
    @property
    def prop(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (super(B, self).prop, 'B.prop')

>>> b = B()
>>> b.prop
'A.prop - B.prop'
```

Comment: Ah, how did I overlook that? :) So you think properties are better than custom methods? Do you know or suspect something about the design decision of the Django team?

Comment: I would say that they chose methods over properties because this part of the framework is expected to be overwritten very often and _explicit is better than implicit_.

Comment: As for properties vs. methods in general: it depends :) I usually start with plain attributes and change them into `@property`-s once some dynamic behavior is needed (also described here: http://blaag.haard.se/What-s-the-point-of-properties-in-Python/). I prefer methods when overriding is expected because it may not always be obvious that something that looks like an attribute is in fact a result of several method calls in the inheritance chain.

Comment: Ok, that point about `explicit is better than implicit` makes sense. Especially when the functions do more than just being getters (e.g. changing `self`). But I think I prefer simple "getter" properties over explicit functions as they are more concise and more DRY (no `get_foo` that does nothing than returning `self.foo`).